# how to make more than one bootstrap carousel slider dynamically on one page

Tags: php, css, twitter-bootstrap, slider, carousel

I create more than one slider dynamically using php but prev or next button is working only in first slider and not in rest slider due to having same class in control, other ones are not working. Please help me to fix this.
here is my slider code with php

```
if($counter == 0)
    {
        //$image_path='<div class="panel-body" style="background-image: url('.$rowu['event_image'].');>';
        $Indicators ='<li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="'.$counter.'"  class="active"></li>';
        $slides = '<div class="item active" >
        <div class="container-fluid" style="marign:0px;padding:0px; background-image: url('.$rowu['event_image'].');">
       <div class="highlighted">'.$event_category.'</div>
        <div class="highlighted">'.$event_city.'</div>
        <div class="highlighted">'.date_format($startDate,'d F').'</div>
        <div class="pull-right" style="margin-top:270px">
          <a href="event.html" class="btn btn-primary">Book</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      </div>';

      }
else{
    //$image_path .='<div class="panel-body" style="background-image: url('.$rowu['event_image'].');>';
        $Indicators .='<li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="'.$counter.'"></li>';
        $slides .= '<div class="item">
        <div class="container-fluid" style="marign:0px;padding:0px; background-image: url('.$rowu['event_image'].');">
        <div class="highlighted">'.$event_category.'</div>
        <div class="highlighted">'.$event_city.'</div>
        <div class="highlighted">'.date_format($startDate,'d F').'</div>
        <div class="pull-right" style="margin-top:270px">
          <a href="event.html" class="btn btn-primary">Book</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      </div>';

}
$counter++;     
        }

        echo '
        <div class="panel panel-default"  style="font-family: Futura,Trebuchet MS,Arial,sans-serif;">
<!-- panel body where slider will work -->
<div class="panel-body">
  <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
     '.$Indicators.'
    </ol>

    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner">
    '.$slides.'  
    </div>

    <!-- Controls -->
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide="next">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
    </a>
  </div>
```

`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

each slider should have a unique ID

```
<!-- Controls -->
<a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide="prev">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
</a>
```

as you see it controls `#carousel-example-generic`

Also it's same for bullets

```
<li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="'.$counter.'"></li>
```

data-target define the slider.